# How do I Start with PhoneGap on GitHub?

Tags: cordova, github, phonegap-build

I would like to start using PhoneGap. I created project in [github](https://github.com/moshfeu/exampleApp) and built it using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps). When I download this to my android device `onDeviceReady()` is not fired. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html, move your JavaScript code in to the HTML body from the header.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phoneGap.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Find Contacts</p>

     <script type="text/javascript" >

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="Bob"; 
        var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        }
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was updated the code like this, and it's not working.. I added alert in the  onDeviceReady() and it's not firing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not include the phonegap.js file in your project when using PGB.

I know it sounds weird, but you make the call to get the JS and PGB will automatically add it on a per platform basis, at build time.

So based on this call in your index.html file,

> < script type="text/javascript" src="phoneGap.js">

PGB will add the Android version or the IOS version, etc, to the final build for the each individual OS.

However it should be:

> < script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js">

See here: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app

So delete the phonegap.js file from your reop and pull the latest into PGB and rebuild.